# Chrome/Firefox: Latest versions with major HTML5/CSS3 improvements?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox, browser-support

We are currently developing an intranet application framework for large companies, based on HTML5/CSS3.
For our browser compatibility matrix, we are currently evaluating the minimum supported browser versions, since statements like "latest extended support release" are rather vague and not quite satisfying for our customers.

For Internet Explorer, the answer is simply "11".

But for Firefox and Chrome, since both browser follow this rapid release cycle, it seems more complicated.

My question is:
Is there some information available anywhere, which previous versions of Chrome or FF were major milestones in respect to implementation and support of important HTML5/CSS3 (maybe even Javascript) features and could thus be used as a lowest supported version?

Comment: Maybe use http://cssnext.io/ and have less of that to worry about directly?

Comment: I don’t think there are any such “major milestones” in the latest releases. Most of the HTML5 and CSS3 stuff that is working today, has been implemented a while ago already – at least concerning “important” stuff such as f.e. flexbox, that might completely break an app/layout. And you’re testing your application in different browser versions anyway, right? So you should know from which versions onwards your app works as expected, and where it’ll start to break.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, @CBroe! I'll propose that we include the latest two ESR release into our test cycles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Firefox

Firefox has an [Extended Support Release](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/organizations/faq/). Currently it's **Fx ESR 45.0**.
It's been released less than a month ago (there was a beta before that) so if your product has already shipped, you may want to stick to Fx ESR 38.0 for a while (if your framework still need months of dev, you can stick with Fx 45.0 :) )

Next update of Fx ESR will be Fx ESR 45.1.0 with all the security and bugfix of Fx 46.0 but none of the new features (see diagram in above link).
Next ESR major release will be Fx ESR 52.0 in approx. 10 months with all new features of Fx 52, then probably Fx 59, etc

---

## Chrome

I don't know of any ESR version on desktop. If your framework has mobile support than it's a different (and complex) world. Mobile has some quirks as stated by PPK a while ago http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2014/09/25_of_mobile_ch.html (can't find again an article about pre-installed mobile browser sort of Chrome 18 that won't ever update vs Chrome installed afterward which is updated but it's old).
Sticking with some version of Android is a good start IMHO and 4.4 is feature-rich enough (particularly [Flexbox **wrap**](http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox)). You may want to support or degrade gracefully on much older versions of Android, YMMV.

The main feature that has been at last implemented everywhere "recently" that no Autoprefixer or CSSNext will be able to bring to your project for older browers is wrap for Flexbox in my opinion.
You need either a polyfill or graceful degradation and Modernizr or drop support for those *not that old* browsers (and don't get me wrong those [PostCSS tools](http://postcss.parts) are AWESOME but they can't do sth that isn't possible in pure CSS).

edit: tangible infos about support of HTML5/CSS3/JS/SVG (and countless others like WOFF2) are on **[caniuse](http://caniuse.com)** : either feature by feature like [flexbox](http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox) (please tell me if you find a faster way than always having to click on "Show all" button :p) or global comparison of versions, like [4 new features in Fx31 vs Fx 30](http://caniuse.com/#compare=firefox+30,firefox+31).

Comment: Many thanks for this solid answer. Indeed, our framework is responsive and we support mobile browser. So this is something more complicated. BTW, today I learnt about a "business version" of Google Chrome: http://smallbusiness.chron.com/chrome-vs-firefox-business-58100.html